# LogIn Window using Hide() method

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a wpf aplication whit the login screen containing textboxes for : user, password and server that allows me to remoteconect to local server.
After i am connect how can i save my login details so i can use them on the next window where i have combobox that lists all my databases in server. 
I tried to use the hide() metod for login window to keep the curent user logedin and to be able to populate the combobox but it didnt work.
Anyone can advice me how shoud i implement it in another way...
The Log in window is the main window yes. 
I create second window from codebehindC# like this

```
DBSettingView win1 = new DBSettingView();

        DelayedExecutionService.DelayedExecute(() =>
        {
            ConnectToSql(tbServer.ToString(), tbUser.ToString(),   tbPassword.ToString());

            this.Hide();

            win1.Show();
        });
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Close-voting.

Comment: You need to post some code. How are you opening these windows? Is the window you are opening after login a new exe? Is the login window the MainPage.xaml? Details kimosabi.

Comment: `The Log in window is the main window yes` That's your problem.  It shouldn't be the main window.  You should have something that should actually be used for the entirety of the application be the main window.  Then either show the login window before opening the main window, or have it shown as your main window is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a class to store those values:

```
public static class LoginSettings
{
    public static string UserName { get; set; }
    public static string Password { get; set; }
    public static string Server { get; set; }
}
```

and then when the user clicks the button to submit the settings, set them:

```
LoginSettings.UserName = txtUserName.Text;
...
```

After you're done with that, close the login form and load the other one. When you want the settings, just get them:

```
var userName = LoginSettings.UserName;
...
```

Comment: so the login form shoud contain this loginsettings class? or both of the forms shoud contain it

Comment: @DaniDărăban, the `LoginSettings` class can be contained in its own `.cs` file. It's a `static` class and thus is visible to all other classes via the `TypeName.Member` syntax.